# Finding Private Keys on Windows

Tags: ssl, private-key

I am using wireshark to intercept SSL traffic that is being sent from my machine. Because it is encrypted on my machine, the private key for the connection has to be stored there... correct?

Is there an application that will just show my the private keys. I guess it would kind of be a security vulnribility if it were easy though.

correct me if I am wrong, but because I encrypt out going connections with the servers public key, and decrypt incoming with my private key, I can only decrypt incoming connections... correct?

Comment: You always encrypt with private key and decrypt with public. Direction of the connection is not important here.

Comment: Private keys are stored in the registry AFAIK. Access is protected using DACLs. You can get this info if you have enough privileges.

Comment: I am full admin, this is my machine so privileges are no concern. Any idea the key name in the registry?

Comment: I was playing with this years ago... Try creating new key mannualy and search the registry for props. Or make export and run windiff before and after.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing several things here.

1. You don't necessarily have a private key at all in a client;
2. an SSL *server* practically always has a private key; but
3. SSL is not encrypted with public/private keys, it is encrypted with a symmetric session key which is generated for the session using the algorithm defined in [RFC 2246](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by EJP, this is only relevant if you're running a server, not a client.

If running a server, the location and format of the key used is detailed in the specific server's configuration. Some servers also include a procedure for exporting this key, which is inside a container or keystore.

Note also that even if you do obtain the private key, certain SSL cipher suites- notably those using the Diffie-Hellman key exchange mechanism - will prevent Wireshark from decrypting the traffic.